# Prove side $c$ of a Triangle equals $\frac{0}{2}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

So in $\triangle ABC$ with angle $\theta$ we can calculate
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - 2ab\cos \theta $$
$$\cos\theta = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab} $$
$$\Longrightarrow$$
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - 2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}$$
$$2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab} = a^2 + b^2 - c^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow$$
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2 - c^2$$
$$c^2+c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2$$
$$2c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2$$
$$c = \sqrt{\frac{0}{2}}$$
How did this happen? I'm sure I did something wrong.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I just forgot the brackets
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)$$

Comment: New contributor, well defined question more or less, no suggestion to improve the question... and 2 downvotes in half an hour!!! Not a great welcome... (+1 to balance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BRACKETS!!!

$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - 2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}$$
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)$$
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - a^2 - b^2 + c^2$$
$$c^2 = c^2$$

This is an excellent question to learn to use brackets :-)

Answer (score 3):

$$2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab} = a^2 + b^2 - c^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow$$
$$c^2 = a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2 - c^2$$

These two equations are not equivalent at all. You messed up not one, but **two** signs.

The original equation simplifies to
$$a^2+b^2-c^2 = a^2+b^2-c^2$$ which is trivially true, but also does not imply $c=0$.

---

Also, as advice, if you get similar nonsensical equations in the future, I suggest you plug in numbers from an actual triangle. For example, take a very simple case where $a=b=c=1$, in which case you also know that $\phi=\frac\pi3=60^\circ$ and $\cos\phi = \frac12$. Now check which equations are still valid, and which are not:

$$\begin{align}
c^2 &= a^2  + b^2 - 2ab\cos\theta 
&
1^2&=1^2+1^2-2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot\frac12
\\
\cos\theta &= \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}
&
\frac12 &= \frac{1^2+1^2-1^2}{2\cdot 1\cdot 1}
\\
\Longrightarrow\\
c^2 &= a^2  + b^2 - 2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}
&
1^2&=1^2+1^2-2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1^2+1^2-1^2}{2\cdot 1 \cdot 1}
\\
2ab\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab} &= a^2 + b^2 - c^2
&
2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1^2+1^2-1^2}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1} &= 1^2+1^2-1^2
\\
\Longrightarrow
\\
c^2 &= a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2 - c^2
&
1^2&=1^2+1^2-1^2+1^2-c^2
\\
c^2+c^2 &= a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2
&
1^2+1^2&=1^2+1^2-1^2+1^2
\\
2c^2 &= a^2  + b^2 - a^2 + b^2
&
2 \cdot 1^2&=1^2+1^2-1^2+1^2
\\
c &= \sqrt{\frac{0}{2}}&&1=\sqrt{\frac02}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: your right, I also tried that with numbers and got the same result, but also I did not messed it up $a\frac{x}{a} = \frac{ax}{a} = x$ so $2ab\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} = \frac{2ab(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{2ab} = a^2+b^2-c^2$

Comment: @DanielWright Of course you messed up. The equation $2ab\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} = a^2+b^2-c^2$ does **not** imply the equation $c^2=a^2+b^2-a^2+b^2-c^2$. The two equations are not equivalent. What you should have is $$c^2=a^2+b^2-a^2+b^2+c^2$$ which differs from your solution by two signs.

Comment: yes it does not imply to equation $c^2 = a^2+b^2-a^2+b^2-c^2$ but I'm just sayin $2ab\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} = a^2+b^2-c^2$ that imply equation $$c^2 = a^2+b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)$$

Comment: @DanielWright Well, of course. But if you wrote that, then I wouldn't have said you messed up.

Comment: I edited the question before I say it